Colima Rosetta option not working with Sonoma 14.7
I have installed via brew colima which is on the latest version available via brew 0.7.5
This is on an m2 pro chipset which should be able to support rosetta.
When I try to enable rosetta support in colima and I try to start colima the following is printed.

[hostagent] Setting up Rosetta share
[hostagent] Unable to configure Rosetta: failed to create a new rosetta directory share caching option: unsupported build target macOS version for 14.0 (the binary was built with __MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED=130300; needs recompilation)

Do I need to wait for a new version of Colima here?

Is there a reason you need an Intel version? Could you use the Apple Silicon version?

hey @SteveM  I don't need the intel version is there something in the error message suggesting I am?

To clarify I do need to run intel version of containers.

I installed the development version with
brew install --HEAD colima

All is now working as expected. For those wondering Rosetta gives a very welcome speed boost for my usecase of running amd64 containers.
